# Can I use crossfire with two AMD GPU with different chipset but similar performance?

Tags: gpu, crossfire

I have an MSI R7 360 and I want to add an ASUS RX 550 to get better performance.

Is that possible or always the GPUs must be exact the same?

Comment: They do not always need to be the same, but they should at least be of the same build or "Family".  Trying to crossfire MSI with an ASUS product will most likely not work.  Also, they are not of the same series.  (R7 VS RX)

Comment: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Crossfire-Chart.aspx

Comment: Thanks!, The R7 doesn't figure on that chart, so Is not Crossfire compatible?